# How to find runtime of following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I am running **Big O** but totally lost.

`while` *loop* only run `N/2` and `for` *loop* is also `N/2` so it becomes `N**2`?

Am I thinking *correctly*?

```
# Block (a)
sum = 0;
n = N
while n > 0: 
    for i in range(0, n):
        sum += 1;
    n = n // 2

# running times: N/2 * N/2 = N^2/4 >> N^2?

# Block (b)
sum = 0
i = 1
while i < N:
    for j in range(0, i):
        sum += 1
    i = i * 2

# running times: N^2??

# Block (c)
sum = 0
i = 1
while i < N:
    for j in range(0, N):
        sum += 1
    i = i * 2

# running times: N^2??
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
  n = n // 2
```

or

```
  i = i * 2
```

Division (`n = n // 2`) reduces `n` *much faster* then subtraction (`n = n - 1`). Your solution `O(N**2)` would have been correct for `n = n - 1`; for the *division* (`n = n // 2`) we have

```
  n = N
  while n > 0: 
    for i in range(0, n):
        sum += 1;

    n = n // 2
```

Let's unwrap outer loop (`while n > 0:`)

```
 0..N              - N      items to sum
 0..N / 2          - N/2    items to sum
 0..N / 4          - N/4    items to sum
 ...
 0..N / 2**p       - N/2**p items to sum
 ...
 0..N / 2**(log N) - 1      item  to sum
```

So we have (*upper bound*):

```
 N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... 1/2**p + ...) = 2 * N = O(N)
```

running lime is *linear*.

Comment: Thank you. how does "0..N - N items to sum ...0..N / 2**(log N) - 1      item  to sum" become N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... 1/2**p + ...)?